# Authoritative source on human cytogenetic regions?

Tags: assembly, human-genome

I am looking for a database that would keep track of  human cytogenetic regions and genomic coordinates per genome assembly. I had expected the Genome Reference Consortium to have it, or Ensembl, or NCBI, but I could not find it.

Is there a place with a translation table between human cytogenetic regions and genomic coordinates?

### EDIT

After benn's answer I found that you can also get this information from Ensembl's REST API: https://rest.ensembl.org/info/assembly/homo_sapiens?content-type=application/json&bands=1.

I have transformed the data provided by Ensembl and generated a CSV file with the cytogenetic regions:

https://github.com/ramiromagno/gwasrapidd/blob/master/data-raw/cytogenetic_bands.csv

Comment: Do you look for a database a paper with a table or what? To which genome should these genomic coordinates be from?

Comment: @llrs: I was looking for a database that would keep track of these definitions per genome assembly. I had expected the Genome Reference Consortium to have it, or Ensembl, or NCBI, but I could not find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean cytoband coordinates? For the human genome you can find them for example at UCSC.

```
hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/database/cytoBand.txt.gz
```

Comment: Hey thanks!, do you know why is there in `hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/database/` also the file `cytoBandIdeo.txt.gz`? I checked, and it has exactly the same info as `cytoBand.txt.gz`. BTW: do you know what the fourth column in `cytoBand.txt.gz` means? It has values like: `gneg`, `gpos25`, `gpos50`, `gpos100`, `acen`, etc..

Comment: The answers can be found on [google](https://groups.google.com/a/soe.ucsc.edu/forum/#!topic/genome/Lymdl_dJvYQ).